# How to perform the modular reduce of Rijndael's finite field

Tags: aes, modular-arithmetic, finite-field, rijndael

I am trying to understand how to calculate the modular reduction of Rijndael's finite field.

The example on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) page says that `{53} • {CA} = {01}`, because `(11111101111110 mod 100011011) = {3F7E mod 11B} = {01} = 1`.

I am able to get to the point where I have `3F7E mod 11B`, but cant seem to figure out how the reduction works.

```
      11111101111110 (mod) 100011011
     ^100011011     
       1110000011110
      ^100011011    
        110110101110
       ^100011011   
         10101110110
        ^100011011  
          0100011010 
          ^100011011 <-- here, right shifted two places?
            00000001
```

From this example, why does it right shift two places at one point?

I also found an example that `0x1b*0xaa` equals `0x8c`. Trying to solve this myself I get to the point: `0xE0E mod 0x11B`

```
 111000001110
^100011011
  11011010110
 ^100011011
   1010111010
  ^100011011
    010001100
   ^100011011
     10010111
```

This makes it `0x97`

Comment: IIRC Rijndael calculates on _polynomials_ instead of integers. Thus each bit you set is actually some power of x which is present in the polynomial.

Comment: Only if there is a leading 1 you should xor a left shifted 0x11b to your intermediate result to cancel out that 1. If you have a leading 0, you create a 1, which you do not want to have there. That's why there was the double shift, and that's what you are doing wrong in the last example.

Comment: @j.p. & SEJPM Please avoid providing answers via comments. Comments should only be used to ask for clarification etc. (In case of doubt, read the placeholder text of the comment box edit field.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let us have a look at the division of $\mathtt{0x3f7e}$ by $\mathtt{0x11b}$

```
1      11111101111110 |    (mod) 100011011
2     ^100011011      +-----------------------
3     +-------------+ |          1?????
4       1110000011110 |                >> 1
5      ^100011011     |
6      +------------+ |          11????
7        110110101110 |                >> 1
8       ^100011011    |
9       +-----------+ |          111???
10        10101110110 |                >> 1
11       ^100011011   |
12       +----------+ |          1111??
13         0100011010 |                >> 1
14        ^000000000  |
15        +---------+ |          11110?
16          100011010 |                >> 1
17         ^100011011 |
18         +--------+ |          111101
19           00000001 |
```

The result of the Euclidean division is therefore:
$$\mathtt{0x3f7e} = \mathtt{0x11b} \times \mathtt{0x3d} + \mathtt{0x1}$$
Or :
$$\mathtt{11111101111110} = \mathtt{100011011} \times \mathtt{111101} + \mathtt{1}$$
Thus:
$$\mathtt{11111101111110} \equiv 1 \pmod{\mathtt{100011011}}$$

As we don't care of the result of the division but only of the residue, we directly forget it.

As you noticed each line there is a single right shift (`>> 1`) in the subtraction. But also notice that when a bit of the quotient is 0, nothing is being done after this right shift  (see lines $\texttt{12}$ to $\texttt{15}$) (because we multiply the divisor by 0, the result will obviously be the same after the subtraction... by 0).

Thus we can *factorize* the lines $\texttt{14}$ to $\texttt{16}$ by double right shift (`>> 2`), giving us the Wikipedia division:

```
1      11111101111110 |    (mod) 100011011
2     ^100011011      +-----------------------
3     +-------------+ |          1?????
4       1110000011110 |                >> 1
5      ^100011011     |
6      +------------+ |          11????
7        110110101110 |                >> 1
8       ^100011011    |
9       +-----------+ |          111???
10        10101110110 |                >> 1
11       ^100011011   |
12       +----------+ |          1111??
13         0100011010 |                >> 2
17         ^100011011 |
18         +--------+ |          111101
19           00000001 |
```

### TL;DR: the double right shift correspond to the $\mathtt{0}$es in the quotient.

About: $\mathtt{0x1b} \times \mathtt{0xaa} \equiv \mathtt{0x8c} \pmod{\mathtt{0x11b}}$

[image]

And looking back at your division:

```
1     111000001110
2    ^100011011
3      11011010110
4     ^100011011
5       1010111010
6      ^100011011
7        010001100
8       ^100011011  <-- THIS IS VERY WRONG
9         10010111  <--
```

Lines $\texttt{8}$ and $\texttt{9}$ are simply not allowed:
$$\mathtt{10001100} < \mathtt{10001101}$$
Thus $\mathtt{10001100}$ is the result and by a strange coincidence $\mathtt{10001100} = \mathtt{0x8c}$.