# AES. Algorithm of multipication in finite field

Tags: aes, implementation

I multiply 2 numbers using their polynomial representation and addition via XOR. Do I need to find the remainder of the division by $x ^ 8 + x ^ 4 + x ^ 3 + x + 1$, using the operator "%" or by division, using the rules of finite fields?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Keep a while we find you a good duplicate. In short $x ^ 8 = x ^ 4 + x ^ 3 + x + 1$ use this identity. That is very common in Finite Field applications that eliminates the polynomial division/remainder.

Comment: [How to perform the modular reduce of Rijndael's finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40742/18298) [How is multiplication in field GF(28) done?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59311/18298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is multiplication in field $GF(2^{8})$ done?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59311/how-is-multiplication-in-field-gf28-done)